# How to create and call cloud code functions on parse-server?

Tags: rest, docker, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm trying to run some very basic cloud code function on my parse-server and I get the same error every time: 141 Invalid function. I'm just adding a main.js file with my function in the cloud directory and trying to call it using Postman, but it looks like the file is not even called.

I've tried locally and on a docker, if the function exist or not I get the same result, and tried restarting the docker container after adding the code. I also tried adding a body to the request with parameters like master and functionName.

Here's my cloud code function (cloud/main.js):

```js
Parse.Cloud.define('hello', function(req, res) {
  return "function called";
});
```

Calling the function with a POST request on https://myurl/parse/functions/hello
and getting:

```
{
    "code": 141,
    "error": "Invalid function: \"hello\""
}
```

Comment: What version of Parse Server are you running?

Comment: I'm running 3.3.0

Answer (score 1):

The `response` object has been removed from Parse Server Cloud Code post `v3.0.0`.

Your Cloud Code function should look like this...

```
Parse.Cloud.define("hello", async (request) => {
  return "function called";
});
```

Please read the [migration guide](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/master/3.0.0.md) for more details on updating your cloud code to `v3.0.0` or above.